# Only single card in android activity of recycler view

Tags: android

I have a list containing 3 items in all. I want all the 3 items in the list to be rendered over 3 different CardView of RecyclerView.
However, it displays only 1 card.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{
        private List<DishBO> dishItemsList;

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            CardView cv;
            public TextView dishName,dishPrice,dishQuantity;
            public ViewHolder(View view){
                super(view);
                cv=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.dishListCardView);
                dishName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dishNameEditText);
                dishPrice=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dishPriceEditText);
                dishQuantity=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dishQuantityEditText);
            }
        }

        public MyAdapter(List<DishBO> dishItemsList){
            this.dishItemsList=dishItemsList;
        }

        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
            View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dish_list_row,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder,final int position){
            DishBO ob=dishItemsList.get(position);
            TextView textViewDishName=holder.dishName;
            TextView textViewDishPrice=holder.dishPrice;
            TextView textViewDishQuantity=holder.dishQuantity;

            textViewDishName.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getDishName()));
            textViewDishPrice.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getCostPrice()));
            textViewDishQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getQuantity()));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount(){
            return dishItemsList.size();
        }

}
```

dishItemsList is a list of 3 items.

Comment: would you please provide full adapter class?

Comment: Please send the xml files of item and activity too...

Comment: Adapter looks fine. Please properly check how many data on the list. If list have 3 data then another chcek of recyclerView height. Hope you can find your problem and also the solution.